# Downloading from links in an rss feed

Tags: python, rss

I am trying to create a directory with news articles collected from an rss feed, meaning that whenever there is a link to an article within the rss feed, I would like for it to be downloaded in a directory with the title of the specific article as the filename as as a text file.
Is that something Python can help me do ?

Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse RSS feeds with [feedparser](https://code.google.com/p/feedparser/) and download files with [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html). If you need to parse HTML use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). If you have any problems with those, post more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. BeautifulSoup, lxml, urllib2, urlgrabber.